# jQuery get biggest number from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
var one = 1415;
var two = 2343;
var three = 11;
```

How to get the biggest number from these variables?

Comment: Can't you stick them in an Array?  Then do some sorting?

Comment: `biggest=two` is quite short. Could be shortened further by using shorter variable names.

Comment: what does jQuery have to do with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have them in an array, you can do this:

```
var numbers_array = [1415, 2343, 11];

numbers_array.push( 432 ); // now the array is [1415, 2343, 11, 432]

var biggest = Math.max.apply( null, numbers_array );
```

Comment: @WorkingHard - You use `.push()` to add items to the top of an array. I'll give an example in my answer.

Answer (score 22):

Math.max(one, two, three)

Comment: @WorkingHard, you can use either Math.max.apply(null,[3,2,1]) or sort array (by desc) and take the first element - [1,4,3,2].sort(function(a,b){return a<b?1:a>b?-1:0})[0]

Answer (score 1):

Put them in an array, sort them, and take the last of the sorted values:

```
[one, two, three].sort(function (a, b) {
  return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
}).slice(-1);
```

Comment: Todd, actually, there's no any guarantee, that array will be sorted numerically. You should sort this way - [n1,n2,n3].sort(function(a,b){return a>b?1:a<b?-1:0})

Comment: Interesting, I didn’t realize that. It sorts each item based on its string representation, so 30 comes before 4.

Answer (score 1):

If your values are in an array, try reduce :

```
var biggestValue = myArray.reduce( function(a,b){ return a > b ? a : b ; } );
```

Comment: It looks like IE8 (at least, possibly further down) doesn't support Array.reduce.  Either use a different method outlined here or you can add compatibility code  [from Mozilla Reference Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

That will work 100%

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, "your array");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function biggestNumber(){
    return Math.max.apply(this,arguments);
}

var one= 1415;
var two= 2343;
var three= 11;
```

**biggestNumber(one, two, three)**

/*  returned value: (Number)
2343
*/

Comment: Why wouldn't you just call `Math.max` regularly in that case?

Answer (score -1):

```
 var number=[12,34,54,32,11,2]

 var big= Math.max.apply(null,number);
```